# How to compare two values as strings using robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

**How to Match the values when objects are unequal,but they are strings.**

> ${tab}=    Get Text    xpath=.//*[@id='projectTable_info']  ${selected
>   text}=    Fetch From Right    ${tab}    of  ${selected text}=    Fetch
>   From Right    ${tab}    of  ${sele}=    Fetch From Left    ${selected
>   text}    entries  ${empno}=    Get Table Cell
>
>   xpath=.//*[@id='projectTable']    3    6  Get Value    ${empno} 
>   ${only value}=    Fetch from Right    ${empno}    |  Should Be String 
>   ${only value}    ${sele}  Convert To String    ${only value}  Convert
>   To String    ${sele}  Should Be Equal    ${only value}    ${sele}

It gives error in console
Fails if objects are unequal after converting them to strings.
INFO    Argument types are:  
FAIL    2 != 2

Comment: your code is garbled.

Comment: Here are more and better options to compare strings - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952283/how-to-search-for-empty-string-compare-two-strings-in-robot-framework/52952887#52952887

Answer (score 7):

Instead of [Should be equal](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal), you can use [Should be equal as strings](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal%20As%20Strings) which converts the values to strings before doing the comparison.

```
Should be equal as strings    ${only value}    ${sele}
```

Your code seems to be attempting to manually convert the values to strings which is also a reasonable solution. Unfortunately, the documentation for [Convert to string](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Convert%20To%20String) is a little vague causing you to use it incorrectly. The keyword doesn't *change* the argument, it *returns a new string*.

If you want to manually convert your variables, you need to do it like this:

```
${sele}=          Convert to string    ${sele}
${only value}=    Convert to string    ${only value}
Should be equal   ${only value}    ${sele}
```

Comment: "Should be equal as strings" may not solve the problem when values are <type unicode> and <type int>; \n However, "Should be equal as integers" will not have this side effect, which is recommended. \n I'm using it to equals the HTTP STATUS CODE.

Comment: @GaGa_Ek: correct. However, this question was about comparing strings, not integers.

Answer (score 0):

This script tries to convert input to float and compares the values in Python 2:

```
def should_be_x_than (self, number1, relation, number2):
    '''
    This keyword makes relation between 2 numbers (it converts them to number)
    Accepted relations:
    < > <= => =
    '''
    if relation =="<":
        return float(number1) < float(number2)
    if relation ==">":
        return float(number1) > float(number2)
    if relation =="=>":
        return float(number1) >= float(number2)
    if relation =="<=":
        return float(number1) <= float(number2)
    if relation =="=":
        return float(number1) == float(number2)
```

After that I imported the library and used it like a keyword (`Should Be X Than`).

**Example**:

```
Should Be X Than  ${num1}  <  ${num2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using evaluate is the easiest, especially when rc need

```
[Documentation]    = / compare two string \ =
${rc}=    evaluate    'name'=='theon'
Log To Console   \n${rc}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare(number1, relation, number2):
    if relation == "<":
        assert float(number1) < float(number2)
    if relation == ">":
        assert float(number1) > float(number2)
    if relation == "=>":
        assert float(number1) >= float(number2)
    if relation == "<=":
        assert float(number1) <= float(number2)
    if relation == "=":
        assert float(number1) == float(number2)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).